# Kubernetes: master node listed in 'kubectl get po' list?

Tags: kubernetes

With the latest kubernetes code pulled from github today.

Steps: Run docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/master.sh on one Ubuntu server called dpcdd3. Alternatively, here is the URL:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/master.sh

```
# kubectl get no
NAME      LABELS                          STATUS    AGE
dpcdd3    kubernetes.io/hostname=dpcdd3   Ready     1h
```

(note: worker.sh is not invoked just yet on second server).

*On an older code (selected randomly from approx a month ago), the same command, in identical setup:  'kubectl get no' would give back nothing.*

Here are some current run-time details:

```
# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2+", GitVersion:"v1.2.0-alpha.6.239+a5d2c1b0fb23a1", GitCommit:"a5d2c1b0fb23a145c47935f041a036d8546cd01f", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.3", GitCommit:"6a81b50c7e97bbe0ade075de55ab4fa34f049dc2", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Interestingly, the pods are shown with status: 'pending':

```
# kubectl get po
NAME                READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
k8s-master-dpcdd3   0/3       Pending   0          1h
```

Some more details:

```
# kubectl describe po 
Name:           k8s-master-dpcdd3
Namespace:      default
Image(s):       gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.1.3,gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.1.3,gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.1.3
Node:           dpcdd3/
Labels:         <none>
Status:         Pending
Reason:
Message:
IP:
Controllers:    <none>
Containers:
  controller-manager:
    Container ID:
    Image:              gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.1.3
    Image ID:
    Command:
      /hyperkube
      controller-manager
      --master=127.0.0.1:8080
      --v=2
    QoS Tier:
      cpu:              BestEffort
      memory:           BestEffort
    State:              Waiting
    Ready:              False
    Restart Count:      0
    Environment Variables:
  apiserver:
    Container ID:
    Image:              gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.1.3
    Image ID:
    Command:
      /hyperkube
      apiserver
      --portal-net=10.0.0.1/24
      --address=0.0.0.0
      --etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001
      --cluster-name=kubernetes
      --v=2
    QoS Tier:
      cpu:              BestEffort
      memory:           BestEffort
    State:              Waiting
    Ready:              False
    Restart Count:      0
    Environment Variables:
  scheduler:
    Container ID:
    Image:              gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.1.3
    Image ID:
    Command:
      /hyperkube
      scheduler
      --master=127.0.0.1:8080
      --v=2
    QoS Tier:
      cpu:              BestEffort
      memory:           BestEffort
    State:              Waiting
    Ready:              False
    Restart Count:      0
    Environment Variables:
No volumes.
No events.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Namespace:      default
```

should be

```
Namespace:      kube-system
```